# Sql procedure is giving error when I pass input parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I have created following procedure but it is giving me error

```
PROCEDURE profileMigration20 compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning
1/30           PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   current delete exists prior
```

```
create or replace Procedure profileMigration20(@firstname varchar(40))
is
   Begin    

    INSERT INTO DPS_USER(ID
    ,LOGIN
    ,AUTO_LOGIN
    ,PASSWORD
    ,MEMBER
    ,FIRST_NAME
    ,MIDDLE_NAME
    ,LAST_NAME
    ,USER_TYPE
    ,LOCALE
    ,LASTACTIVITY_DATE
    ,REGISTRATION_DATE)

    select ID                   
    ,LOGIN
    ,AUTO_LOGIN 
    ,PASSWORD           
    ,MEMBER             
    ,FIRST_NAME         
    ,MIDDLE_NAME            
    ,LAST_NAME          
    ,USER_TYPE          
    ,LOCALE             
    ,LASTACTIVITY_DATE  
    ,REGISTRATION_DATE  
   FROM NM_DPS_USER where FIRST_NAME=@firstname;
  End;
```

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves me right...

It looks like you're using the wrong syntax (it looks like the T-SQL syntax used with MS SQL).

To use parameters in pl/sql the syntax should be:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE procedure_name ( 
  param_name1 IN datatype, param_name12 IN datatype ... )
```

In your case:

```
create or replace Procedure profileMigration20(firstname IN varchar2(40))
```

and to use it just call it without the @ sign like:

```
FROM NM_DPS_USER where FIRST_NAME=firstname;
```